# Does the `helm-projectile` package use an index?

Tags: helm-projectile

Do the commands of the `helm-projectile` package consult an index, or do they scan the entire project tree every time they are invoked?

In case they use an index: when is this index created and updated? Is there an explicit way to create/update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a cache that you can invalidete with `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache`. See chapter `caching` in [this article](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) for more information.